# Stream.Flush() not work at HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Timeout = REQUEST_TIMEOUT;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/form-data";

byte[] data = new byte[1024];
var readNumber = localFileStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    var len1 = readNumber / 2;
    stream.Write(data, 0, len1);
    stream.Flush();
    stream.Write(data, len1, readNumber - len1);
    stream.Flush();
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

When I do `stream.Flush()`,it is not blocked. I think this should be blocked until all the data is sent. But it seems the data is sent when `request.GetResponse()` is executed. Did my understanding have problems? Or what can I do to achieve this effect.
Thanks for your enlightenments.

Comment: the code down the line of `GetResponse` will read from the stream. There is no way to "push" anything, the actual http request is not initiated earlier.

Comment: I do just want more accurate statistics upload speed, it seems that it can not do so.

Comment: yes, then you're asking for a solution that cannot solve the original problem. Give asynchronous requests a try, there you can subscribe to a progress event that notifies your application as it proceeds with an upload: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadprogresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Set
`HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false`
and
`HttpWebRequest.SendChunked = true`